# Python error with hello.py traceback

Tags: python

I'm very new to Python. I am having an issue with my hello.py command. It gives me the following error:

```
C:\Users\Admin>python hello.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "hello.py", line 1 in <module>
        if _name_ == "_main_":
NameError: name '_name_' is not defined
```

Comment: Use double underscores, not just one: `__name__` etc.

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you - it worked perfectly!

Comment: @tonya-nichols You got good ansver. But would be good to show Your hello.py

Answer (score 2):

Try using 2 underscores before and after name and main, so:

```
__name__
```

And

```
__main__
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in your `hello.py`:

```
def myfunction():
   print "hello!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
   myfunction():
```

---

## In other words

Enclose the code you have in the `hello.py` script in a function wrapper (`myfunction()` in above example). Now, when executing `hello.py` from the **command line**, the `myfunction()` will be called by the `if __name__ == "__main__":` part)

---

## [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for) another way

If you want to `import hello.py` as a Python module in another Python script, say anotherPython.py. Place an empty file in the same directory as the `hello.py`, whose name is exactly: `__init__.py`. Then in the anotherPython.py, write:

```
import hello
hello.myfunction()
```

That should then print "hello!" when executed in Python.

Comment: @TonyaNichols I have provided two possibilities, let me know how it goes. But I have, for now, also flagged the question for migration to Stack Overflow. I also tried to remove sentimental statements from your question.